# How to use complex data types from External Dependencies with DllImport in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a win32 API library .dll file for some hardware that I need to access in c#. I believe using DllImport to create a wrapper class for the .dll that makes it usable in my C# uwp application.

The first function I believe have done correctly 
(C code)

```
ADIOLIB_API
aDIO_Error WINAPI aDIO_General_Enum(aDIO_Enum_Info* DeviceList,
                                uint8           ListSize)
```

(C# code)

```
[DllImport("aDIOLib.dll")] static extern aDIO_Error aDIO_General_Enum(ref aDIO_Enum_Info DeviceList, Byte ListSize);

public static aDIO_Error aDIOGeneralEnum(ref aDIO_Enum_Info DeviceList, Byte ListSize)
    {
        return aDIO_General_Enum(ref DeviceList, ListSize);
    }

public struct aDIO_Enum_Info
    {
        UInt32 dev_num;
        aDIO_Intrfc_Avail availability;
        UInt32 base_address;
        UInt32 irq;
        bool has_wake;
    }
```

aDIO_Error is just a UInt32 error code, so that part has been handled as well.
When I moved on to the next function to create a wrapper for it I ran into this issue. So the function header is like this:

```
ADIOLIB_API
aDIO_Error WINAPI aDIO_General_Open(aDIO_Enum_Info  DeviceInfo,
                                    aDIO_Handle*    Handle)
```

After thinking the aDIO_Handle is probably another struct that I have to replicate in C#, I looked at the declaration for it and found this:

```
typedef struct
{
    /**
        Holds a critical section object used to control access to all library
        state and functionality.
    */
    CRITICAL_SECTION global_lock;

    /**
        Holds a handle to the aDIO device file. (Used to send IOCTLs to the
        driver.)
    */
    HANDLE dev_file;

    /**
        Holds device/board information retrieved from the driver.
    */
    aDIO_Intrfc_Board_Info dev_info;

    /**
        Holds a critical section object used to control access to the error
        logging function and the last error message.
    */
    CRITICAL_SECTION log_section;

    /**
        Holds the last un-retrieved error message.
    */
    char last_error_msg[ADIO_ERROR_MAX_MSG_LENGTH];

    /**
        Holds a pointer to the structure holding the state of the Interrupt
        module.
    */
    void* int_state;

} aDIO_Descriptor, *aDIO_Handle;
```

Both the HANDLE and CRITICAL_SECTION types are from external dependencies (minwinbase.h and winnt.h) in which this dll has like 100s of external header files. How am i supposed to make a DllImport for this aDIO_General_Open function without recreating all the header files in the process.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Please ask me questions to clarify if you have any! I am new to this DllImport stuff

Comment: Why do you need to declare the struct in your C# code?  Can't you just work with a pointerbtonthe struct.

Comment: Well, if you have hundreds of header files that you want to fully interop with, there's no magic bullet, you'll have to declare more or less all these. If some structs are opaque, you can just pass pointers around, but that doesn't change the heart of the problem. Another solution is to write a COM wrapper in C/C++ with a TLB that you can pretty automatically reference from C#. This can be considered again if you want to open all your object model. But it's not a free ride either...

Comment: @SimonMourier I was wondering if a wrapper in C/C++ might be the way to go in this situation. Thank you for confirming that there is no easier way to do this that I couldn't find and that that is a possibility, I think that is the direction I will take.

Comment: You don't need to translate every header file in its enterity. And I don't even think you need to translate this struct. Nothing in the code you provided shows any requirement for the C# code to have knowledge of the layout of the struct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan wouldn't it have to know about the struct layout to use it as an argument in the function though?

Comment: Not if you only ever pass a pointer to the struct, and have the dll allocate and deallocate the struct which looks like it might be the case here.